# Gstreamer- Duration query error on mp3

Tags: c, mp3, gstreamer

I am working on a simple application using Gstreamer on C, that involves playing a song and show some info about it on terminal. Thta info includes the total length of the song in seconds. As usual, I used the function gst_element_query_duration to get this data. The thing is, when I run my program, sometimes it shows the right time on screen, but then I run it again and the total time showed is about 6 seconds less. Because is just a simple trial application, I am using **playbin** as the general bin for reproduction, so I tried with different file extensions and it seems this only happens with mp3 files. Have anyone ever experienced this? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

MP3 has the problem that there is no duration stored inside the file (usually). With constant bitrate files you can simply check the bitrate and the file size, but for variable bitrate files you can only do an approximation based on that. Your problem is probably exactly that.

The only way to know the exact duration of a variable bitrate MP3 file without header information with the duration (see Xing header) is to parse the file until the end and count the exact duration. With playbin you should get the accurate duration at the end of the file.

Comment: I actually noticed that when I queried the duration after the pipeline EOS, the results were always accurate, so I guess you are right. Anyways, thanks for your help!